# In the O level CIE exam, what differences are there in structures between articles in paper 1 and paper 2?

Tags: exam-questions

I'm going to take O level CIE exam and this is something I'm quite confused about.

What are the differences in structures between articles in paper 1 and paper 2?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because itis not about the English language.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to talk to your teacher.  Paper 1 tests writing skills, Paper 2 tests reading skills.

See the [syllabus online](https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/programmes-and-qualifications/cambridge-o-level-english-language-1123/)

In paper 1 you will have one directed task and one composition task.  The directed task will be something like "write a speech in {some school situation} Your speech must contain {this information}"  The composition task is to write an essay or story on one of a choice of prompts "Write an essay about why sport is important in school" or "Write a story about a lost dog"

In paper 2 you must summarise a text and answer questions about a story. These questions test if you understand the key ideas in a factual text, and if you are able to understand the meaning of a short story.